# How can we use first countability here

Tags: general-topology

To start we define fist countability as "$X$ is said to be first countable if and only if $X$ has a countable basis at every point $x \in X$. This means that $X$ has countable basis at $x$ if and only if there is a countable collection $\mathcal{B}_x$ of open subsets containing $x$ such that for any open subset $U$ with $x \in U$ there is a $B\in \mathcal{B}_x$ such that $B \subseteq U$." If we let $\mathcal{T}$ denote the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ as $$\mathcal{T} = \{U \subseteq \mathbb{R}| U = \emptyset \hspace{2mm}\mbox{or} \hspace{2mm} \mathbb{R}-U \hspace{2mm} \mbox{is countable}\}$$

The question is asking to use first countability to show that $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T})$ is not metrizable. The case where $U = \emptyset$ seems trivially true that this space is not metrizable, and I think I have that one down. In terms of the case where $\mathbb{R} -U$ is countable, how does that affect if this space is metrizable. We know that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, so I assume that $U$ must be uncountable, however, does an uncountable set - an uncountable set yield a countable set, or what set $U$ would make this a true statement?

Comment: I believe you need to first revise your understanding of what a topology on a set is. Here, $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology on $\mathbb R$, so I am not sure what you mean by "*$U=\emptyset$ seems trivially true that this space is not metrizable*". $U=\emptyset$ is merely an "open set" from $\mathcal T$, and we are talking about metrizability of $(\mathbb R, \mathcal{T})$ here.

Comment: **Hint**: All metrizable spaces must be first-countable, because there is always a countable basis of neighbourhoods about a point $x$: the open balls $B(x,\frac{1}{n})$, for $n=1,2,3\ldots$, in whatever metric you can find! So, can you prove that $(\mathbb R,\mathcal{T})$ is *not* first-countable?

Comment: $V:=\mathbb{R}-U$ would be a countable set of real numbers and of course $\mathbb{R}-V$ will still be uncountable. There is a theorem called "Bing-Nagata-Smirnow" which states that there must exist some countable base, which might be contradictory, but I don't know the exact argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to show that if $x\in\Bbb R$, there is no countable base at $x$ in the topology $\mathcal{T}$. Since every metrizable space is first countable, this would shot that $\langle\Bbb R,\mathcal{T}\rangle$ is not metrizable.

HINT: Let $x\in\Bbb R$, and let $\mathscr{B}=\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ be any countable family of open nbhds of $x$. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $C_n=\Bbb R\setminus U_n$, and note that each $C_n$ is countable. Let $C=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}C_n$; then $C$ is countable; why? Let $U=\Bbb R\setminus C$. Use $U$ to find an open nbhd of $x$ that does not contain any member of $\mathscr{B}$, and conclude that $\mathscr{B}$ is not a base at $x$ and hence that there is no countable base at $x$.